# managed and unmanaged

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, clr, managed-code

if a .net dll contains both managed and unmanaged code , how does the code will be converted to CIL and how CLR allocate and manages the memory

Comment: Are you asking about safe/unsafe code or managed/unmanaged interoperability? There is a difference, and it's important to be precise.

Answer (score 9):

The unmanaged code is by definition *not* managed by the CLR. It will not be converted to CIL, and the CLR will neither allocate nor manage memory for it. That only happens for the managed code.

When you write unmanaged code in a .NET assembly, you're instructing the compiler and the run-time that you want to take matters into your own hands. You become responsible for memory management, just as if you were writing native code.